# Creating routers for multiple database in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am developing a Django application in which I need several databases, one for each user of the system. For this I defined the databases like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'primary': {
        'NAME': 'primary',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    },
    'user1': {
        'NAME': 'user1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    },
    'user2': {
        'NAME': 'user2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    },
}
```

In which the database `user1` and `user2` are replicas of the structure of `primary`.

Let's say I created two superusers, with the logins 'superuser1' and 'superuser2'. How do I define that when 'superuser1' is logged the data is changed in the database 'user1' and when 'superuser2' is logged the data in the database 'user2' is changed?

Comment: Do the users authenticate against `primary`?

Answer (score 0):

This logic is likely going to span across your application. Effectively you will need to create a function that would take a user instance and then return a string that will map to a database:

```
DATABASE_USER_MAP = {
    'username1': 'user1',
}

def get_database(user):
    return settings.DATABASE_USER_MAP.get(user.username, 'default')

def some_view(request):
    data = Data.objects.using(get_database(request.user)).all()
    ...
```

Once you get something like that working, you could move the database determining logic into a middleware and set it on `request` so that you could do:

```
def some_view(request):
    data = Data.objects.using(request.db).all()
    ...
```

The main concern with this is that it would default to `primary` rather than error out forcing you to be meticulous when writing queries.

Another avenue you may want to pursue is diving into Django's codebase to see how the database router works and if you could get the request sent as a hint to the router. I don't know anything about it, so I don't know if it's possible. However, if that were possible it'd eliminate the concern I raised.